# Firebase onAuthStateChange fire twice when login

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am fully aware of the function onAuthStateChange fire immediately after register but this is not the case. I am having a problem with this function fire twice after the user sign in with their username and password. The first time it fires up, I trace back to the stack and it comes from my code, but the second time, it comes from Firebase JS file itself. I am quite confused since I don't understand why they fire up. I am using web version of Firebase. The code is provided beneath.

TL;DR: I am using web version of Firebase. The function onAuthStateChange fire twice AFTER the user sign in with their username and password.

```
// callback function
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    console.log("change");
    if (authCounter == 0) {
        authCounter = 1;
    } else {
        if (user) {
            currentUser = user.uid;
            dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child(currentUser);
            handleEvent(9);
        } else {
            handleEvent(10);
        }
    }
});

// sign in function
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).catch(function(error) {
            displayError(error.code);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to have any errors.

I had the same problem before. I thought the listener was being called twice but actually, it was the login function that was being called twice/unnecessarily (you don't need to be logged out to login so everything looked fine, except for the fact that the listener was fired twice).

Also, you are not auto logged out when you reload the page, so you might be already logged in (fired for the first time) when you call the login function (second time).

That's what I could think of, hope this leads you in the right direction.